# Is there a PHP bundler similar to Node's Webpack

Tags: php, node.js, webpack, bundler, slim

I wrote a REST-API application using PHP Slim4 framework. However, now that I want to deploy the application. I cannot seem to find an intuitive tool like webpack to bundle my app into a few files and do the tree shaking for any unused code.

Are there any tools that people use with PHP for deployment? I'm not used to deploying PHP apps so I'm not sure what are the best practices for deploying PHP applications into the wild?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need tree shaking in PHP, you can load needed classes using lazy loading. For that you need [*autoloading*](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.spl-autoload-register.php) which can load the class file when the class is needed.

Instead of implementing the logic yourself you should use the, de-facto standard, [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and use the [PSR-4 convention](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) to make your file paths match your namespaces.

If you really want to have everything in one file you can use the [phar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php) "archive", you can do it manually or with tools like [box](https://github.com/box-project/box) but you don't need it to deploy code in production, it's usually not needed.

Comment: yes i am using namespaces and composer autoloader. However, how can I remove all comments and spaces from the scripts? there are also a few options (in the entry file) that I need to switch when going to production. For example, displaying errors turned to false, etc.

Comment: You should use a "dotenv" (https://www.12factor.net/), for example this project https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv will load the .env file as environment variables. Then you can conditionally do things for dev or prod.

Comment: Thanks for Box and DotEnv mentions, they're great tools that really fits well to this topic. Should Box be used to encapsulate applications for deployment in CI/CD environments or would it be a bad practice?

Comment: To test you won't need it, you can test your source code directly on the CI, it could potentially be handy to use box if you want to create a "build" to share or deploy but it's often not necessary. Unlike js, you deploy the php code in production without transformations because it's server side.

Answer (score 2):

You can use composer to generate an optimized build of your application. All dev-dependencies are removed and the Composer autoloader is optimized for performance.

Run this command in the same directory as the project’s composer.json file:

```
composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

You don’t have to run composer on your production server. To build a deployment "artifact" you could use Apache Ant.